# Persist data on disk using chrome extension API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage, chrome-sync

I am trying to save some data which should be available even when restart the browser So this data should persist. I am using `Chrome Storage Sync` API for this. But when I am restarting my browser, I get empty object on using `chrome.storage.get`.

Here is my sample code:

```
SW.methods.saveTaskListStore = function() {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    'taskListStore': SW.stores.taskListStore
  }, function() {
    if (SW.callbacks.watchProcessSuccessCallback) {
      SW.callbacks.watchProcessSuccessCallback(SW.messages.INFO_DATA_SAVED);
      SW.callbacks.watchProcessSuccessCallback = null;
    }
  });
};

SW.methods.loadTaskListStore = function() {
  SW.stores.loadTaskListStore = [];

  chrome.storage.sync.get('taskListStore', function(taskFeed) {
    var tasks = taskFeed.tasks; 

    if (tasks && !tasks.length) {
      SW.stores.loadTaskListStore = tasks;
    }
  });
};
```

I guess I am using the Wrong API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is not some copy-paste error, you are storing under key `taskListStore` and trying to get data under key `loadTaskListStore`.

Besides that, according to the documentation on **[StorageArea.get()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get)**, the result object is an *object with items in their key-value mappings*. Thus, in your case, you should do:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("taskListStore", function(items) {
    if (items.taskListStore) {
        var tasks = items.taskListStore.tasks;
        ...
```

Comment: yep loadTaskListStore was a typo..Edited the question..I think you are right I am using the API wrong way. Let me try once again with your suggestion